# semantic security of RSA variant

Tags: rsa, semantic-security

I am thinking of a variant of RSA. 
I know that RSA itself is not semantically secure as it is "deterministic". I have a "randomized" variant of RSA in mind.

Suppose that the public key is $<e,n>$. To encrypt a plaintext $p$, this variant first randomly choose a value $v$, and output the ciphertext as:
$$E(p)=<v,(v+p)^e \text{ mod }n>$$
The ciphertext consists of 2 parts, the value of $v$ in clear, and the ciphertext of $(v+p) \text{ mod }n$ computed using the original RSA.

Is this variant of RSA **semantically secure**? How do I prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not.

As a reminer: [Semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security) is equivalent to IND-CPA. Semantic security is less commonly used, because most of the time proofs are less intuitive and more difficult.

In the IND-CPA game, the attacker chooses two messages $m_0,m_1$ and sends them to the challenger. The challenger chooses a bit $b$, and sends $Enc(m_b)$ to the attacker. The attacker wins if he can guess $b$ correctly. And we consider the encryption scheme secure, if the advantage of the attacker compared to random guessing is negligible.

So, let's play the CPA game with this variant:

- The attacker chooses $m_0$ and $m_1$ arbitrary (but not equal)
- He gets back $Enc(m_b)$. In your scheme that would be some value $v$ and $(v+m)^e \mod n$.
- Since he knows both $m_0$ and $m_1$, he can check both possibilities by calculating both $(m_0 + v)^e$ and $(m_1 + v)^e$. Comparing that with the challenge, he immediately knows $b$
- The attacker wins.

If you want to have an IND-CPA RSA variant, there is [RSA-OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding). In the random oracle model and with the RSA assumption, this is proven to be IND-CCA2, which is much stronger than IND-CPA.

Answer (score -2):

If you intercept the message `<v,c>` and instead transmit `<v+x, c>` it will decrypt to p-x.
So this doesn't seem secure.

Edit: Just to clarify, I was a bit sloppy here.
What I was going for is the fact that malleability precludes IND-CCA2. But the question was actually about semantic security and there are in fact semantically secure malleable schemes. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_%28cryptography%29))

So while the statement "doesn't seem secure" is technically correct for the most widespread definition of "secure" for PKE schemes I did not answer the question at all. Sorry.

Comment: "most widespread definition of "secure" for PKE schemes" I would not agree with that. IND-CPA has its value, especially since it allows (semi-)homomorphic encryption schemes. (the positive side of malleability). Also IND-CPA is a good abstraction for symmetric encryption with proper mode-of-operation (but, that's not PKE). And I don't think there are that many practical IND-CCA2 schemes besides the case of RSA-OAEP. For ElGamal, according to [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26867/is-elgamal-ind-cca1) even CCA1 seems to be an open question.