# Key-Privacy in Postquantum Public-key Encryption

Tags: encryption, lattice-crypto

is there any post-quantum public-key encryption that achieves "key-privacy" (IK-CPA, IK-CCA) as described in this [paper](https://iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480568.pdf)?

I saw one [code-based](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-59879-6_3) public-key encryption construction, but I wonder if there is any lattice-based construction.

Comment: As per the following discussion, we can see that NTRU scheme is secure against CPA and CCA. Please let me validate if it offers IK-CPA, IK-CCA . https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33769/which-attacks-are-possible-against-raw-textbook-ntru-encryption